# Issue with 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' and samba installation

Tags: raspbian, samba, raspberry-pi-os, dpkg

I've been trying to install Samba on my Raspberry Pi, but seem to have created a broader issue in the process.

The steps to the issue were the following:

- I ran the install code:
  `sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin`
- The install got stuck after a while, on the following message:

> Setting up samba (2:4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u1+rpi1) ...
> Samba is not being run as an AD Domain Controller: Masking samba-ad-dc.service
> Please ignore the following error about deb-systemd-helper not finding those services.
> (samba-ad-dc.service already masked)

- Now, I can't install anthing, nor remove the partial samba install. Any attempt ends in

> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

- Running the suggested command leads me back to the samba error message above.
- I have tried all I could find online. Those had no effect:
  `sudo apt-get -f install`
  `sudo apt-get clean`
  Nor did killing the four processes running that refer to smbd.
- The only thing that seemed to change something was
  `sudo dpkg --clear-selections`
- However, as soon as I launch any install after that, such as
  `sudo apt-get upgrade`
  I end up back in the same loop.
- I also tried removing samba with
  `sudo apt-get remove --purge samba`, but it went back to the same loop too.

I can live with not installing samba, but not being able to install anything is more of a problem. Anyone who could help me solve the issue? Thanks!

Comment: The likely quickest solution is to write a fresh image to the SD card (after making a copy of anything you need).

Comment: "the samba error message above" - it's not an error, it even says `Please ignore the following error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After continuing to search on the issue, I think I have solved it. I ran the following:

- `sudo apt-get autoclean`
- `dpkg –-remove samba`
- `dpkg –-purge samba`
- `apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove` (not 100% certain about the order)

Then, I ran again

- `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

For some reason, the issue seems resolved.

Thank you all for your help!

EDIT: Further to this, I have resolved the underlying issue that prevented me from installing samba:

- After removing everything, I tried to install it again, but got stuck at the same step as my first message. The RPi shutdown again and I was faced with the same error message and error/crash loop.
- I ran `dmesg` and somewhere there was a message saying `Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)`
- I had not thought of this, because I was running an older RPi on the same power supply, but this one seems to need more amperage.
- I switched the power supply (the phone charger in this case) to a more recent one, with Quick Charge, and ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Samba install completed.